# Helper function with `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` that would resume on the main thread

Tags: swift, concurrency

I'm working on adopting Swift 5.5's concurrency features into my app and starting off with a single method. This is what I have so far:

**Utility Method**

```
static func fetch<T: GraphQLQuery>(
    query: T,
    cachePolicy: Apollo.CachePolicy = .default
) async throws -> T.Data? {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        Task {
            let network = try await Network.shared
            network.fetch(
                query: query,
                cachePolicy: cachePolicy
            ) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    do {
                        continuation.resume(with: .success(try result.get().data))
                    } catch {
                        continuation.resume(with: .failure(GraphQLResultError.default))
                    }
                case let .failure(error):
                    continuation.resume(with: .failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging I found that continuations are resumed on an arbitrary method and not the thread they're being called. From my example above, `network.fetch`s callback is always on the main thread, but `continuation.resume` once again shifts execution to an arbitrary thread.

**Model code**

```
static func fetchData() async throws -> [SomeData] {
    let query = SomeQuery()
    do {
        let data = try await Util.fetch(query: query)
        // Still on a background thread
        return data!
    }
}
```

**View Code**

```
private func fetchData() async {
    do {
        let data = try await Model.fetchData()
        
        // This feels incorrect since this will be set after the `fetchData` function returns
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            result = (Result.success(data), [:])
        }
    } catch {
        result = (Result.failure(error), [:])
    }
}
```

I thought there'd be some way to do be able to run the continuation of the main thread from within the `fetch(query:)` method so that I don't have to switch to the main thread when I'm setting properties on each of my views. Is this one of the use cases for `MainActor`? How would I do this if I don't want to use `MainActor`?

Comment: Never mix `async await` with `DispatchQueue`, use `@MainActor` on the function or class, it would be best to rewrite `network.fetch` within `Network` so you can get rid of that floating `Task` it is a recipe for a leak since you lose control. Watch "Meet async await"

Comment: Once you get past your current problem, you might consider a broader code review (e.g., https://codereview.stackexchange.com)…

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll definitely post a sample there.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your “view code”, where you are dispatching code to the main queue:

```swift
private func fetchData() async {
    do {
        let data = try await Model.fetchData()
        
        // This feels incorrect since this will be set after the `fetchData` function returns
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            result = (Result.success(data), [:])
        }
    } catch {
        result = (Result.failure(error), [:])
    }
}
```

In Swift concurrency, we no longer use old GCD “dispatch” pattern. Instead, if we have a property or methods that we want run on the main thread, we just isolate that it to `@MainActor`:

```swift
@MainActor
private func fetchData() async {
    do {
        let data = try await Model.fetchData()
        result = (Result.success(try await data, [:])
    } catch {
        result = (Result.failure(error), [:])
    }
}
```

Or you could put this method within a type that is isolated to the main actor. That would achieve the same thing.

---

FWIW, many coming from GCD gravitate to `MainActor.run {…}`, which is reminiscent of our old friend, `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}`. But we really want to use the global actor designation, `@MainActor` for things that must be performed on the main thread, because we now enjoy compile-time validation of our concurrency code.

For practical tips in converting legacy code to `async`-`await`, I might suggest WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/). It is a good practical demonstration of this migration process.

Comment: Thanks, Rob! This definitely is a valid solution. Alternatively, how would you achieve this if you want to dispatch to the main queue within my continuation in my utility method so that I can avoid having to switch to the main actor in each of my views?

Comment: “how would you … dispatch to the main queue within my continuation in my utility method” … That’s just not how Swift concurrency works. In Swift concurrency, you don’t “dispatch” (and your attempts to do so will likely only introduce inefficiencies). The thread used internally by the continuation is immaterial. If your view method is isolated to the main actor (which it should be), the final update of the property will happen on the main thread. Frankly, your time would be better spent making `Network.fetch` a proper `async` method than worrying about this.